# iphone data synchronization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, data-synchronization

I'm new to iphone development. I currently have an app on windows mobile that uses a local database on the device (sqlce) and the app is able to synchronize the data between the device and a remote database through a web service using microsoft sync framework.

Is this requirement feasible on an iphone app? Id like to build a version of my app on the iphone. I see that the iphone can use sqlite for storage on the device.

But does the sdk have something for data synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to use JSON or XML to get the data from your remote server via a NSURLConnection and write the code to synchronise the sqlite db on the iPhone. There are plenty of JSON frameworks for the iphone and for the XML route you can use NSXMLParser.